# Why poi excel export not working in my spring project?

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

As I am Korean, I apologize for my poor English.

I'm trying to implement a spring project in which the db value can be downloaded to Excel using the 'poi library'.

My code doesn't work.
There are no errors in the log, so I don't even know why.
Does anyone know my code doesn't work?

Getting data from the DB is becoming clear.

Since it's a company project, I change the variable name and upload it.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/export/excel.download")
@ResponseBody
public void ExcelDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    List list=tempService.getDataList();


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( );
    String fileName = "excel_"+cal.getTimeInMillis();

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet(fileName);

    XSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("first");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("second");
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("third");
    row.createCell(3).setCellValue("fourth");
    row.createCell(4).setCellValue("fifth");
    row.createCell(5).setCellValue("sixth");
    row.createCell(6).setCellValue("seventh");
    row.createCell(7).setCellValue("eighth");

    for (int i = 0, rowIndex=1; i < list.size(); i++) {

        Map item = (Map) list.get(i);

        row = worksheet.createRow(rowIndex+i);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(item.get(0).toString());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(item.get(1).toString());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(item.get(2).toString());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(item.get(3).toString()+" Days");

        if(item.get(4)!= null) 
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(item.get(4).toString());


        String checkUseYn[]=item.get(5).toString().split(",");

        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(checkUseYn[0]);
        row.createCell(6).setCellValue(checkUseYn[1]);
        row.createCell(7).setCellValue(checkUseYn[2]);

    }

    UtilFunctions.downloadExcel(request, response, workbook, fileName);

}
```

**UtilFunctions.downloadExcel**

```
public static void downloadExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, XSSFWorkbook workbook, String fileName) throws Exception{

    if(workbook != null) {
        String filename = fileName+".xlsx";
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;charset=euc-kr");
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        if(userAgent != null && userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 5.5") > -1) 
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") + ";");
        else if(userAgent != null && userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) 
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "ATTachment; Filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") + ";");
        else
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "ATTachment; Filename=" + new String(filename.getBytes("euc-kr"), "latin1") + ";");

        response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache;");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1;");

        OutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            workbook.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please define what *does not work* means? Do you get an empty document? Does the dowload not start?

Comment: i use poi version 3.15

Comment: Even empty documents cannot be downloaded. just getting the data from the DB.

Comment: Please describe what happen when you access `/export/excel.download` with your browser.

Comment: There is a button to access url. Press button to access the controller through ajax. List list=tempService.getDataList(); this code works. Repeated sentences seem to work well, too. But downloads don't work.

Comment: If you use ajax your client (the js part) should handle it, the browser won't. So if you expect a popup that won't happen when doing an ajax call. Either make it a regular link or handle it appropriatly in your ajax aprt.

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but I just want a download function. There is no additional pop-up, and only the function that requests url is handled by ajax when clicked purely.

Comment: It's not a Ajax request. I used location.href. and success! It was too simple. I'm sorry to get stuffy. Have a nice day!